# Sort sub-lists with 2 values with id composed of a string with sequential digits in the end

Tags: sorting, ironpython

I have a list composed of sublists:
Each sub-list has always two values in the same order:
[id, value]

Each id is composed of a letter indicating a function (W, F, H or R) than a position level (A to Z)and then a placement/creation order (A sequential number).

So a list would look something like:

```
[[WA1, value],[WA2, value], [HA3, value]....[WA122, value][HA123,value]]
```

I have tried to sort using

r.sort(lambda x,y: x[0][1:]) in hopes that I would get a partial string as the key but it failed.

```
pn = input1
th = Input2
i=0
r=[]
for p in pn:
    r.append([p, th[i]])
    i+=1

r.sort(lambda x,y: x[0][1:])
```

I get a Traceback error on the last line.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer after trying for some time

```
sorted(r, key=lambda x: (len(x[0]), x[0][1:]))
```